# link_to blank space

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3

I have changed the regular labels for view, edit and delete for background images for the corresponding `<td>` labels. But now the link don't work because I don't have text to click.

How can I make blank spaces clickable, or is there another approach to this problem?

This is what I got:

```
...
<td class="view"><%= link_to '', event %></td>
<td class="edit"><%= link_to ' ', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
<td class="delete"><%= link_to ' ', event, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

I know a solution is to add the image as image_tag and create a link, but having the images declared in the style.css is much more cleaner and simple to implement.

thanks in advance

Comment: The solution is to use normal images instead of background images. Or use css. Anyway, this question really doesn't have to do anything with Ruby on Rails.

Comment: can I do that in the css? because adding image_tags in the views is my last option

Comment: Why is that your last option? What's wrong with image tags? In css you can set the class for your blank links to `display:inline-block;width:100%;height:100%;`. That should make them clickable. But from a usability perspective, I think you should just use image tags.

Comment: I have tons of different views and <td>'s that have "clickable" images. If I decide to change the image later I'll have to change all of them one by one again.

Comment: I have added what you said to td.view but nothing happened, I still can't click the <td>

Comment: You have to add it to the link. Not to the `td`.

Comment: @ShibinRagh: You can use jQuery, but IMO, for something like this it's overkill.

Comment: Thanks Mischa, that solved the problem. Please add it as a answer and I'll mark it as solved. THANKS!

Comment: Glad it works. Added it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the link clickable by using CSS. If you set the class for your blank links to:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

they should become clickable.

Comment: Thanks again. I know little to nothing about css, this code did what I needed.